# Issues with autoincrementing in Sheets based on form edit/submission

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Very new to Google Apps Script here.  I borrowed some code for this assign invoice number function from a prior post.  The intent is to autoincrement an identifier field in sheets which is receiving submissions from a form.  I've also provided an EditURL field to allow users to easily get back and edit the records in the form.  A trigger runs on form submit for this.  If they edit a pre-existing record, then the last record in the list is incrementing based on the code. (BAD) I've tried to insert what I though would be a valid IF statement to evaluate if this last cell was empty first, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  Actually, the second part: {

```
nextCell.setValue(maxInColumn+1)
  }
```

doesn't run at all at that point.  If I comment out the if, it goes back to previous behavior.
Not sure how to make this do what I need...hoping somewhat out there has an idea.  Here's the

code...been hacked a bit.

```
function assignInvoiceNumber() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();

 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var EmptyString = '';
//create an array of the invoice numbers already created 
 var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, lastColumn-3, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();

//sort the array values to find max
 var maxInColumn = colArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0][0];

 var nextCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn-3);


//assign the max+1 to the next entry
  if (nextCell == "") { 
  nextCell.setValue(maxInColumn+1)
  };


}
```

Kind Regards,
Gsmo

Comment: If you want to verify either the contents of nextCell are empty - the `if` statement should be: `if (nextCell.geValue() == "")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function assignInvoiceNumber() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var EmptyString = '';
  var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, lastColumn-3, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  var maxInColumn = colArray.map(function(r){return r[0]}).sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0];
  var nextCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn-3);
  if (nextCell == "") { 
    nextCell.setValue(maxInColumn+1)
  };
}
```